# How to reflect on a different delegate for a string type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

How can one reflect on a different delegate for a string type in C#?

I am trying to just allow it to revert to 'ToString' for a string

```
private static Func<string, T> TryGetParser<T>()
    {
        return typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(string) })
            .CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, T>)) as Func<string, T>; 
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `different delegate`? What do you want to get?

Comment: I am trying to just allow it to revert to 'ToString' for a string

Comment: What do you mean by "revert to ToString"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
private static Func<string, T> TryGetParser<T>()
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        return s => (T)(object)s;
    }
    return typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(string) })
        .CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, T>)) as Func<string, T>;
}

var parser = TryGetParser<string>();    
var foo = parser("bar"); // foo = "bar"
```

Comment: this is great thanks, I tried to cast T to String but it didn't work, still not sure why object works as the second cast, thanks for such a good answer

Comment: As [error docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0030) state this error happens because `T` can be anything and compiler can't find predefined conversion between "anything" and string. Meanwhile you can trick it - everything can be cast to object. And you can try [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#type-conversion-exceptions-at-run-time) object to anything (because everything is an object =) with risk of getting runtime error.

Comment: Thanks that really helps me to understand!

Comment: @user1688726 was glad to help!